# How to find the client IP/name from the audit logs

Tags: linux, nfs, syslog, auditd

I'm auditing the files in a nfs share. When I look at the audit logs using the command `ausearch -f /var/nfs/general` , I get some logs that looks like this:

In the server side:

```
time->Tue Jun 12 16:23:34 2018
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1528800814.660:2782): proctitle=636174002F7661722F6E66732F67656E6572616C2F6E6673312E747874
type=PATH msg=audit(1528800814.660:2782): item=0 name="/var/nfs/general/nfs1.txt" inode=4063539 dev=08:01 mode=0100664 ouid=1001 ogid=1001 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL
type=CWD msg=audit(1528800814.660:2782):  cwd="/home/test"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1528800814.660:2782): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=3 a0=7ffc2c53c824 a1=0 a2=20000 a3=69d items=1 ppid=31104 pid=7295 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts18 ses=4294967295 comm="cat" exe="/bin/cat" key=(null)
```

In the client side:

```
time->Tue Jun 12 10:22:01 2018
type=UNKNOWN[1327] msg=audit(1528779121.923:84671): proctitle=636174002F6D6E742F6E6673332E747874
type=PATH msg=audit(1528779121.923:84671): item=0 name="/mnt/nfs3.txt" inode=4063534 dev=00:2c mode=0100644 ouid=1001 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL
type=CWD msg=audit(1528779121.923:84671):  cwd="/home/salini"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1528779121.923:84671): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=3 a0=7ffd7eeef903 a1=0 a2=1fffffffffff0000 a3=7ffd7eeed870 items=1 ppid=5286 pid=5652 auid=1507 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts8 ses=187 comm="cat" exe="/bin/cat" key=(null)
```

Now how can I get the IP address and the host name of the client who accessed the nfs share files?

Is there any other way to find those details?

I want to gather the details such as time, date, IP address of the client, client host name, event occurred (like read, write, rename, change ownership to the file, delete or create a file in the nfs folder).

The gathered details are to be put in a separate file which can be used for further purposes.

How can I do this?

I'm a linux newbie. Please help me.

Thank You. :)

Comment: Your example looks very much like a local `cat` command...

Comment: I don't think `cat` could do this. How do say it looks like `cat` command?

Comment: The PROCTITLE line says `cat\x00/var/nfs/general/nfs1.txt`. The process title cannot be transferred over NFS (and of course NFS itself doesn't run `cat` to read files), so it must be a locally generated event.

Comment: @grawity Editted post